# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 (SUPEE patch)

Tags: magento-1.7, sql, patches, supee-6788

After installation of SUPEE patches for Magento, some extensions show **"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax"**
I am wondering whether such errors make the site vulnerable to SQL injections or other attacks?
Again, these error show only after supee patch installations.

Comment: Usually, this was an indicator that the modules should have been upgraded prior to patch installation in order to be compatible. And yes, the modules complained about are susceptible to sql injection.

Comment: @FiascoLabs I thought that if patches are installed which often result in modules breaking, then SQL injections cant occur because originally the SUPEE security patches are there to protect against injections. The fact that extension is broken after patch installation means it was not compatible with security. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: That's correct. The error shows that the module was *potentially* insecure **before** the patch was applied. Now it's just not working anymore and has to be updated.

Comment: @fschmengler Thank you! I had a small feeling that even if the patch is installed and the module shows SQLSTATE[42000] error on front page it can be a leeway for SQL injections.